# Are there two types of member initializer lists in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, member-initialization

I saw two different ways to use member initializer lists. The first one is like that:

```
class ClassName {
   public:
      arg_type_1 varName1;
      arg_type_2 varName2;

      // Constructor.
      ClassName(arg_type_1 arg_name_1, arg_type_2 arg_name_2)
      : varName1(arg_name_1), varName2(arg_name_2) 
      {
      }
}
```

What is happening there is clear. In the constructor we have a list of arguments and we use them to initialize members of the class. For example `arg_name_1` is used to initialize value for the `varName1` variable of the class.

Another way to use the member initializer appears in the case of inheritance:

```
class ChildClass : public ParentClass
{
      ChildClass(string name) : ParentClass( name )
      {
           // What can we put here and why we might need it.
      }
};
```

What happens here is also clear. When we call the constructor of the `ChildClass` with one string argument, it calls the constructor of the `ParentClass` with the same string argument.

What is not clear to me, is how compiler distinguish these two cases (the syntax is the same). For example, in the second example, compiler might think that it needs to take value of the `name` variable and assign it to the `ParentClass` variable of the `ChildClass` and then it sees that such a variable is not declared in the `ChildClass`.

The second unclear point to me is why we might want to put some content in the body of the constructor from the second example. Even of there is nothing it already creates and returns an object using the constructor of the parent class.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=e4821da91a1cc5ad112cf44922b310e3-3b440a87a52fe2ae7c853c82f4c5144f) gives a bit of a clearer picture of what happens when the two intersect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is not clear to me, is how compiler distinguish these two cases (the syntax is the same).

Seeing an initializer in the list, the compiler first looks for member variables with that name. If it finds one, it tries to initialize that member with the given arguments. If it does not, it looks for a direct base class or virtual base class with that name, to initialize the base class subobject with the given arguments. These are the usual name lookup rules applied when you name something inside a class' method (including constructors).

In the rare and badly designed case when you have both a member variable and a direct base class with the same name, you will have to qualify the base class type, i.e. add the namespace:

```
struct B1 {
  B1(char const*) {};
};
namespace Foo {
  struct B2 {
    B2(bool) {};
  };
}

struct Weird : public B1, public Foo::B2 {
  int B1;
  double B2;

  Weird() 
    : ::B1("meow")
    , Foo::B2(false)
    , B1(42)
    , B2(3.14)
  {}
};
```

> The second unclear point to me is why we might want to put some content in the body of the constructor from the second example. Even of there is nothing it already creates and returns an object using the constructor of the parent class.

It does not really return any object, it just creates that object. However, someone might want to call additional functions like this:

```
class ParentClass {
public:
  ParentClass(string name);
  void registerSomething(ParentClass const&);
}

class ChildClass : public ParentClass {
public:
  ChildClass(string name) : ParentClass( name ) {
    registerSomething(*this);
  }
};
```

There could be many reasons why someone might want to do this. In General, since the child class is "more" than the parent class, it is only natural if it wants to do more in its constructor than just initialize the base class subobject.

Some words on object lifetimes:
Before entering the constructor body, you have only constructed the subobjects of the new object. The object itself begins its lifetime when execution leaves the constructor body. An analogy could be a car and its parts: Before enterign the car's constructor body, you have inflated the tyres, assembled the enginge and stamped out the parts of the body. But your car isnt a car if it has not been assembled, wich happens in the constructor body. This is mirrored in the destructor and can especially be seen in the presence of exceptions: If an exception occurs during an object's constructor, its destructor will not be called. Only the destructors of the subobjects will be called that have already been constructed completely. This is because if the constructor has not completed execution, the object never existed and there is nothing to call the destructor on.

Comment: Is it a mistake that `registerSomething` does not have a return type (not even void)?

Comment: Yes, that was a mistake, fixed that.

Comment: In the third paragraph: "it looks for a direct base class" should be "it looks for a direct base class or a virtual base class".

Comment: @JamesKanze yes, thank you, I always forget about those. And I don't praticularly like them ;)

Comment: @ArneMertz You can't really write effective C++ without them.  (On the other hand, they will normally be interfaces, with no data members and only a default constructor, so you can ignore them in the initializer list.)

Answer (score 1):

`ParentClass` is a type and `varName1` is a variable. They are two different kinds of entities that every compiler should distinguish.

There are lots of cases when you want put some code in subclass ctor. For example, you want to calculate the initial value of a subclass member based on the proper initialization of base class objects.

Comment: In other words, by this line `ChildClass(string name) : ParentClass( name )` I create an instance using the corresponding constructor of the parent class. Then, if I have some context between the following `{}` brackets, I modify the created object and then I return it. Is it right?

Comment: Strictly, `: ParentClass(name)` is not creating an object but initializing the base part of a childClass object. The memory is already allocated, the constructor is just there to initialize that memory properly. Yes, you can modify the base object/part in subclass ctor body. But you should know that ctor doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Roman I added some words on object lifetimes to my answer. The `ChildClass` constructor body can modify the `ParentClass` subobject, but strictly speaking the `ChildClass` object is not modified because it does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

These are really the same for the compiler: the initializer list
is used to initialize sub-objects.  If the sub-object is a base
class, it is named by its type; if it is a member, it is named
by the member name; but the principle is the same in both cases.

The usual name lookup rules apply.  If you give a member the
same name as a base class, it will hide the base class, and you
cannot specify the base class in the initializer list (which
means that the base class must have a default constructor).
(**Don't do this**.  Establish a naming convention so that type
names and variable names can never clash.)

As to why you might want code in the actual body of the
constructor, there can be many reasons.  Most often, it will be
because of some post-processing you what to do on the
initialized members.  In other cases, it might be because you
need to do some preprocessing before you can initialize the
members.  Or you might want to refactor some common processing
out into a separate function.

Comment: You can specify the base class by fully qualifying it, so no default ctor needed (see my answer). And strictly speaking, you cannot do any preprocessing in the constructor body before member initialization, only before assigning the final values to the members. Entering the costructor body every member is already initialized.

Comment: @ArneMertz Yes, you can specify the base by fully qualifying it.  And POD members _aren't_ initialized if they aren't specified in the initializer list.  You can do quite a bit of preprocessing in the constructor body, if the members have POD type.  (Strictly speaking, of course, you assign rather than initialize, but with POD types, there's no real difference.  The object wasn't initialized before, and it is after.)

Comment: yeah, the contradictory nature of §8.5,6: "Default-initialization [of PODs] means no initialization is performed" so is a default-initialized POD initialized or not? ...

Comment: @ArneMertz Yes.  Default initialization is not an initialization, but assignment isn't initialization, so...  (I was actually using initialization in its more general sense, rather than in the strict sense of the standard.  So that my comments about preprocessing could even apply to an `std::string`: technically, you initialize it empty, then assign to it, but conceptually, the "initial value" is the one you calculate in the body of the constructor).

Answer (score -1):

> What is not clear to me, is how compiler distinguish these two cases (the syntax is the same). For example, in the second example, compiler might think that it needs to take value of the name variable and assign it to the ParentClass variable of the ChildClass and then it sees that such a variable is not declared in the ChildClass.

Compiler knows that `ParentClass` is a type not a member in `ChildClass`. You won't be able to declare a member with name `ParentClass`

> The second unclear point to me is why we might want to put some content in the body of the constructor from the second example. Even of there is nothing it already creates and returns an object using the constructor of the parent class.

This is for the cases where you want to use some specific non-default constructor in `ParentClass`.

Comment: You *will* be able to declare a member with name `ParentClass`.

Comment: `This is for the cases where you want to use some specific non-default constructor in ParentClass.` But even without any content between {} I have already indicated what constructor of the parent class I want to use (default or not).

Comment: In the constructor's body you usually do some stuff that cannot be done through simple initialisation/assignments to class members.